# How to imitate Pythonic indexing of arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

I am translating a code from Python to Julia. I have the following array:

```
_DAYS_IN_MONTH = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

And the following line of code:

```
_DAYS_IN_MONTH[index] - _DAYS_IN_MONTH[index - 1]
```

The idea is that, if `index - 1` is evaluated to -1, then we will get the last element of the array, which is exactly what we need in this case. However, this does not work in Julia. Of course, I can write something like this:

```
if index == 1
    _DAYS_IN_MONTH[index] - _DAYS_IN_MONTH[end]
else
    _DAYS_IN_MONTH[index] - _DAYS_IN_MONTH[index - 1]
end
```

But I wonder if there is a more elegant and "Julian" way of doing this.

Comment: As a tangential note, there's a `DAYSINMONTH` in the `Dates` standard library already. The proper interface to it is a call like `daysinmonth(Date("2022-01"))` since that'll take care of leap year concerns too, but you're also able to access it directly as a `Tuple` with `Dates.DAYSINMONTH`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Effectively what you're after is a very specific case of a [circular array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435965/how-to-index-circular-array-in-julia).  You achieve that with [`mod1`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.mod1).  It'll "wrap around" values outside of the valid indices.  It takes two arguments; the first is the value (the index to wrap) and the second is the modulus (the length of the array).  In the context of indexing, you can just use that special `end` syntax for the modulus:

```
julia> [_DAYS_IN_MONTH[index] - _DAYS_IN_MONTH[mod1(index - 1, end)] for index in 1:12]
12-element Vector{Int64}:
  0
 -3
  3
 -1
  1
 -1
  1
  0
 -1
  1
 -1
  1
```

Answer (score 11):

Another elegant option would be `using CircularArrays`

```
julia> _DAYS_IN_MONTH = CircularVector([31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]);

julia> _DAYS_IN_MONTH .- _DAYS_IN_MONTH[0:end-1]
12-element CircularVector(::Vector{Int64}):
  0
 -3
  3
 -1
  1
 -1
  1
  0
 -1
  1
 -1
  1
```

Or `using ShiftedArrays`:

```
julia> _DAYS_IN_MONTH .- circshift(_DAYS_IN_MONTH,1)
12-element Vector{Int64}:
  0
 -3
  3
 -1
  1
 -1
  1
  0
 -1
  1
 -1
  1
```

Answer (score 5):

No need for extra packages, Julia Base has this one:

```
_DAYS_IN_MONTH .- circshift(_DAYS_IN_MONTH,1)
```